# find_one() return one document give a combination of fields

Tags: python, mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo

I am trying to return a document from my mongodb (using pymongo). I want the query to return a document given an id and a tag.

```
ids = ['123', '456', '234', '534']

rows = []
for i in ids:
    for b in ["Tag1", "Tag2", "Tag3"]:
        temp = pb_db.db.collection.find_one({"ID": i, "Tag": b}, {'ID': 1, 'Tag': 1, 'Name': 1, '_created_at': 1})
        if temp is not None:
            rows.append(temp)
```

A document with an ID of '123' may have one record with 'Tag1' and a separate document with 'Tag3'. Any combination of 'ID' and 'Tag' is possible.

The goal is to return one instance of each id, tag combination (hence using find_one())

At the moment my code above is very inefficient as it queries the db for every id three times (my list of ids is much larger than this example). Is it possible to use the find_one() query to return a document for a given id with each tag only once? Thanks,

example mongo structure:

```
{
    "_id" : "random_mongo_id",
    "Tag" : "Tag1",
    "_created_at" : ISODate("2016-06-25T00:00:00.000Z"),
    "ID" : [ 
        "123"
    ],
},
{
    "_id" : "random_mongo_id",
    "Tag" : "Tag2",
    "_created_at" : ISODate("2016-07-25T00:00:00.000Z"),
    "ID" : [ 
        "123"
    ],
},
{
    "_id" : "random_mongo_id",
    "Tag" : "Tag1",
    "_created_at" : ISODate("2016-07-25T00:00:00.000Z"),
    "ID" : [ 
        "534"
    ],
}
```

so in this example i would expect to see:

```
ID: 123, Tag: Tag1
ID: 123, Tag: Tag2
ID: 534, Tag: Tag1
```

Comment: Could you give an example of the data structure in the database? It's difficult to analyse your query without knowing what kind of data it is querying.

Comment: updated the original post

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could do it in a single pass by using the [$in operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/#op._S_in) to compare the items in the "ID" array in the database with the items in the "ids" array variable, and similarly for the tags.

> Use the $in Operator to Match Values in an Array
>
> The collection inventory contains documents that include the field tags, as in the following:

```
{ _id: 1, item: "abc", qty: 10, tags: [ "school", "clothing" ], sale: false }
```

> Then, the following update() operation will set the sale field value to true where the tags field holds an array with at least one element matching either "appliances" or "school".

```
db.inventory.update(
  { tags: { $in: ["appliances", "school"] } },
  { $set: { sale:true } }
)
```

In user3939059's case, the query would be something like this:

```
ids = ['123', '456', '234', '534']
tags = ['Tag1', 'Tag2', 'Tag3']

pb_db.db.collection.find({"ID": {$in: ids}, "Tag": {$in: tags}}, {'ID': 1, 'Tag': 1, 'Name': 1, '_created_at': 1})
```

Comment: @user3939059 Yes, mongodb's findOne() query uses exactly the same query syntax as find().

Comment: This will not work because `ID` is array in OP's document.

Comment: @Styvane No, it really does compare items in one array to items in the other array. I have edited my answer to quote the mongodb documentation explaining how.

Comment: unfortunately i tested and it returns None. Ill double check

Comment: @user3939059 One other thing I noticed is that in the variable, your ids are numbers (123, 456, etc) but in the data they appear to be strings ("123", "456" etc). Is this deliberate?

Comment: that was my mistake, each id in the list is surrounded by a single quote

Comment: @user3939059 I have edited my answer to put the ids in the array in single-quotes, making them strings - I think that's what you mean?

Comment: thanks, does the in operator work if the ids in the db are in array format but the ids held in the variable are of list format? I think that might be my problem

Comment: @user3939059 Ah yes, it might :(-  I'm not familiar with the interface between python and mongodb, so I don't know for sure.You probably need to check the pymongo documentation to find out.

Comment: @user3939059 I don't think it will cause a problem; from a quick read of the [pymongo documentation](https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/) it transparently converts between python lists and json arrays all the time.

Comment: it runs without error but returns no result and there should be lots of results

Comment: the mistake was on my side - thanks for the solution, it works well.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [`$in`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/) and the [`$elemMatch`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) query operator.

```
ids = ['123', '456', '234', '534']
tags = ["Tag1", "Tag2", "Tag3"]

db.collection.find_one({
    "Tag": { "$in": tags}, 
    "ID": { "$elemMatch": { "$in": ids}}
})
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but this method returns zero results when it should return lots